# WebViewJavascriptBridge and App Rejection

Tags: ios

Using [WebViewJavaScriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge) in iOS app, as per some rejection comments

> Any code which passes arbitrary parameters to dynamic methods such as
> dlopen(), dlsym(), respondsToSelector:, performSelector:,
> method_exchangeImplementations(), and running remote scripts in order
> to change app behavior or call SPI, based on the contents of the
> downloaded script. Even if the remote resource is not intentionally
> malicious, it could easily be hijacked via a Man In The Middle (MiTM)
> attack, which can pose a serious security vulnerability to users of
> your app.

We noticed that there are few occurrences of `dlopen` method in this library,

```
dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit", RTLD_LAZY);
```

anyone faced the issue of rejection with this library.

Ref: [https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge/search?utf8=✓&q=dlopen&type=](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dlopen&type=)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is approved and WebViewJavaScriptBridge working fine for us.